# Delegate - Exceptions don't wait until calling EndInvoke()

Tags: c#, exception, delegates

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        new Program().Run();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    void Run() {
        Action example = new Action(threaded);
        IAsyncResult ia = example.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(completed), null);
        // Option #1:
        /*
        ia.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        try {
          example.EndInvoke(ia);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        */
    }

    void threaded() {
        throw new ApplicationException("Kaboom");
    }

    void completed(IAsyncResult ar) {
        // Option #2:
        Action example = (ar as AsyncResult).AsyncDelegate as Action;
        try {
            example.EndInvoke(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

In many articles stands that when I call `BeginInvoke`, all `Exception`s (here from method `threaded`) wait until I call `EndInvoke` and will be thrown there. But it doesn't work, the `Exception` ("Kaboom") is "unhandled" and the program crashes.
Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to explain what's special about your debugger setup.  At the very least document what you see Debug + Exceptions.  Turn off any check-boxes there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That works fine. When you say "and the program crashes", I'm wondering if you just have the IDE set to break on all exceptions. I get no crash with that - it writes "Kaboom" to the console, as we would expect. Try running it outside of the IDE or pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> instead of just <kbd>f5</kbd>.

I think you are just seeing the IDE being "helpful":

[image]

Ignore that; the IDE doesn't always get it right. That is still handled.

Comment: Thanks :) I had the same window... But when I create my framework and load the DLL to my program, a "unknown" Exception will stop the program, this is not what a framework should do...

Comment: @Luca it is the debugger, not the framework. You can turn it off in the options menu, IIRC

Comment: Yes, but the .NET also works with async methods and I can catch the Exceptions by calling EndInvoke with the SAME debugger configs...

Comment: @LucaNateMahler that setting is actually on an exception-type basis; meaning: it might be enabled for `ApplicationException` but not for `SomeOtherExecption`.

Comment: The only thing that itches is the message "unhandled by user code". True, it's caught by the framework (not user code) and kept until `EndInvoke` is called.

Comment: Remember that an Exception should happen only on exceptional condition, not in normal runs. Hence the useful feature of the debugger to let developer know right when it happens, regardless of when it is handled or not. I recommend (and practice) to have the debugger halt on all (or as many as possible) Exception, just because there shouldn't be any. Not doing so exposes you to missing important opportunities to see and fix problems in your code. The later a bug is fixed the costlier it is.